# How to populate a SharePoint person/group column with a SharePoint group using Microsoft flow

Tags: sharepoint-online, custom-list, list-view-threshold, person, ms-flow

I have a SharePoint task list that has exceeded 5000 items. I have a created a custom list that has just about all the columns of the task list. My intention is to copy a large backlog of the items in the task list to the custom list as a sort of archive. My preferred option for achieving this is using Microsoft flow.
However, one stumbling block I am facing is that the flow fails when the AssignedTo in the task list is a SharePoint group. Apparently, I can't populate "AssignedTo Claims" with the display name of the SharePoint group.
Has anybody faced similar issues? Will deeply appreciate a solution or suggestion.
Thanks.

In addition, I can't use retention policies because it is absolutely essential that I preserve fields such as "Created By", "Modified By", "Created Time", "Modified Time" and if possible attachments. I have created equivalents of these fields in the custom list.

Comment: Instead of using a flow to remove items, why not try using the retention policies in SharePoint to move the items? It's found by going to Library Settings > Information Management Policy Settings (under Permissions and Management) > Select your content type > Select the "Enable Retention" button > Configure. You can have items be deleted, moved, start a workflow, delete versions, etc. Useful tool!

Answer (score 0):

You can set clamins field with the login name of the group.

[image]

You can get the login name via below endpoint:

[image]